Microsoft Teams Notification Password Expiry Issue
Microsoft Graph API - Is it possible send chat message using client credentials flow?
I was using grant type as password to generate bearer token for sending Teams notification with my application (I had done application registration in Microsoft Azure AD). It was working fine, but then it failed and threw the below error.
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50055: The password is expired. Trace ID: 411e883a-ac32-4387-9e08-e4a6cccf8300 Correlation ID: bde4686c-1e78-41d3-bb60-a75190ca8891 Timestamp: 2024-12-03 14:12:36Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50055
    ],
    "timestamp": "2024-12-03 14:12:36Z",
    "trace_id": "411e883a-ac32-4387-9e08-e4a6cccf8300",
    "correlation_id": "bde4686c-1e78-41d3-bb60-a75190ca8891",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50055",
    "suberror": "user_password_expired"
}

When I logged in to teams, it was prompting to update password to login. After changing password, it is working fine now.
But this approach is not feasible since we need to update in regular intervals in production configuration.
Any idea regarding this to keep the password permanent would be very helpful !

You can set up a script or automated process to change the password regularly and update your application's settings. However, this method can be complicated and needs careful management of the credentials.

@Nivedipa-MSFT, how can we implement such a script..?

Using the password grant type for generating bearer tokens is not recommended for production environments due to security concerns and issues like password expiration. Instead, you should send activity feed notifications through the Microsoft Graph API, which uses the client credentials flow to obtain an access token from Azure AD.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/send-activity-feed-notification?tabs=desktop#send-activity-feed-notifications-to-users

Using the password grant type for generating bearer tokens is not recommended for production environments due to security concerns and issues like password expiration. Instead, you should send activity feed notifications through the Microsoft Graph API, which uses the client credentials flow to obtain an access token from Azure AD.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/send-activity-feed-notification?tabs=desktop#send-activity-feed-notifications-to-users
